# How to print top 5 frequently occurring words from a substring

Tags: javascript

I have some project, with finding the bad words from user. How can i find an a top 5 frequently encountered words from the array of "bad words" in user input string?

I try to do it, but this code doesn't work how i want

```
const containsAny = (str, substrings) => {
    for (var i = 0; i != substrings.length; i++) {
       var substring = substrings[i];
       if (str.indexOf(substring) != - 1) {
         return substring;
       }
    }
    return null; 
 }

 var result = containsAny(textWords, listOfBadWords);
 console.log("String was found in substring " + result);
```

i would like to make it like: word - number of times of use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  var filteredArr = topWords.filter(function(item) {
    return item[1] != 0;
  });


  var output = filteredArr.map(function(item) {
    return item[0] + " - " + item[1];
  }).join(", ");
```